# Does pycharm have a command window similar to emacs?

Tags: pycharm

Can I invoke Pycharm commands by name (with completion)? Not by menu, not by keybinding, but by command name (with completion). I'm thinking about something similar to Visual Studio or emacs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, its called "Find Action":

[image]

Comment: Awesome. We have a winnah. Ty.